# c# Download file from sql database, display downloading status

Tags: c#, database, file, download

I have an application in c# and an sql database which i use with it(insert,update,download etc.). My main problem is, when i try to down/up load a file(for exemple a pdf file) from sql database, and the file is big enough or the internet speed is not that fast the program is get stucked. I mean it takes too long time to up/download that file  and until that is finished "nothing happens". I just simple want to show a progressbar or something to show that the dowloading is in progress and show its status.

In details:
The column "fileok" is an image file type

I am trying to download a saved file from a that column like this:

```
dbbyte = (byte[])adattabla2.Rows[0]["fileok"];
```

and uppload a file to database like this:

```
sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FF", FileBytes);
```

It gets/upload the stored file and its takes a while if this big or the net is slow and until its finished its like "freezed". When its done the program continues.
So the program is working I just need to inform the user that it's downloading and show its status.How could i do that?
I could not find anything helpful only for dowload with urls,links but not for database like this.

I would appriciate your help thanks!

Answer (score 1):

use a `BackgroundWorker` with b.e a `ProgressBar`, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447856/displaying-a-progressbar-while-executing-an-sql-query)