# How to dynamically update a textbox text?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, textbox

I am working on a desktop application in which i have to transfer a large amount of data from one db to another.I want to show the details of record transfered in a text box dynamically. i am using following code

After insertion in db following code is executed:

```
if (val >= 0) 
{
   Transfercounter++;
   saving = "Record " + Transfercounter + " is transferred to new DB"; 
   txtResults.Text = txtResults.Text + saving + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine; 
}
```

How to show the transfered record dynamically at run time instead of showing all records after the execution completes.

Comment: I agree @TomSarduy his question is OK +1.

Comment: Amir when do you execute this code? Show us more code.

Comment: @aamir: Maybe you need some client side code to achieve this

Comment: After insertion in db folowing code is executed else if (val >= 0) { Transfercounter++; saving = "Record " + Transfercounter + " is transferred to new DB"; txtResults.Text = txtResults.Text + saving + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine; }  its a Win form app

Comment: Use BackgroundWorker  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx

Comment: update your question with this code

Comment: wtf? is it wpf? asp.net? winforms?

Comment: oh my friend, removed upvote, we are talking about Window Form now. Different question ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Dan Hunex says, you should use the BackgroundWorker approach with ProgressBar and a text box showing status:

[image: Progress bar and textbox on Background Worker]

#### Steps

1. Put your SQL in a BackgroundWorker. Great examples on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) and is not hard to use.
2. When you call the BackgroundWorker, that frees up your UI to run some kind of "Status" control.
3. Once the BackgroundWorker's RunWorkerCompleted happens, you can remove your "Status" control and bind up your data or whatever

#### Further

- If you like ProgressBar, I'd recommend looking at this article on CodeProject: [ProgressWorker](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/progress/ProgressWorker.aspx)
- [Background Worker on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx)
- [Basic tutorial](http://www.dotnetperls.com/backgroundworker) if you are begginer
- [Another tutorial](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/112547-using-the-backgroundworker-in-c%23/)
- A very [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447856/displaying-a-progressbar-while-executing-an-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

Use BackgroundWorker. There is good example in msdn , you can customize that to reach to the effect you want  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx