# How to create progressbars with name from string?

Tags: c#, winforms, loops, progress-bar

As the name implies I'm trying to create progress bars (at runtime). I need this because I have to display in a graphical manner how much, out of 100%, some elements have reached. The elements are extracted from a database and may vary in number so I can't make a fix number, I need a loop that creates the progressbars... I think.
Any way possible?

Comment: you have to use threading to get exact what you want

Comment: Any example or documentation?

Comment: [Please Refer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447856/displaying-a-progressbar-while-executing-an-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

First Extract all the elements from Database............and then set the Extracted elements count to Progress bar.

Comment: I was trying to do just that but how can you set the Design name of the bar?

Answer (score 0):

You can do st. like this:

```
progressBar.Step = 1;
progressBar.Minimum = 0;
progressBar.Maximum =  elements.Count;

...

for (int index = 0; index < progressBar.Maximum; index++)
{
  // Do your work here ...

  progressBar.PerformStep();
}
```

Comment: you are defining the properties of a bar. But how do I declare it? Don't I need some PregressBar pb = new ProgressBar(); or something..?

Comment: @Vantalk, I assumed that you have already placed one on you form.

Comment: I did not. I asked how can I create it at runtime, no placing in design mode or fixed names cause they might be more or less

Comment: You didn't respond to anything I asked. Please come up with a better answer if you have one. Read the entire question

Comment: @Vantalk, stackoverflow is not like, "I want this so give me the code", for the best understanding, you need to post some code and st. you have tried so far.