# How update progress bar with sql query while inserting data

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is for use in a ASP.NET Web Application
I have a few csv files that that I am uploading into the db. When each csv row is inserted i update a progress table as well showing a total number of rows and the current count.

I since it is a large file, I would like to update the progress bar while its processing..
I've walked through this [example](http://www.telerik.com/forums/radprogressarea-help) but dont know how to run both at the same time.

any help or examples would be great!

Comment: A little more context would be helpful. Is this a Windows Forms app? or...?

Comment: The example linked by the OP suggests it's ASP.NET web project.  I see "Page_Load" in there.

Comment: Yes, it is a web app. my apologies for leaving that out.

Comment: This question is similar to this one:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447856/displaying-a-progressbar-while-executing-an-sql-query